Why does my array keep returning "Undefined array key"
I want to retrieve the api data from timezone api by clicking the submit button, for the first table row. Unfortunetly it is showing an error message whenever I visit the url link http://localhost/task/geonamesExample/libs/php/getTimezone.php?lang=en&country=GB. to see the error (even when I try it without going to the link).
I expect it to return a value of latitude once I click on the submit, and it's suppose to display in the last row.
I tried deleting geonames a couple, I've tried using var_dump($decode).

Moreover this is the error message I keep getting 
Warning:  Undefined array key "geonames" in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/task/geonamesExample/libs/php/getTimezone.php on line 25
{"status":{"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"success","returnedIn":"98 ms"},"data":null}

index.html:

    <!doctype html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
    
            <title>AJAX/PHP/CURL/JSON example</title>
            <meta name="description" content="AJAX/PHP/CURL/JSON example">
            <meta name="author" content="Paddy Evans">
    
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
            <select id="selCountry">
                <option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
                <option value="FR">France</option>
                <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                <option value="US">USA</option>
            </select>
    
            <select id="selLanguage">
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="fr">Francais</option>
                <option value="de">Deutsche</option>
            </select>
    
            <button id="btnRun">Run</button>
    
            <br><br>
    
            <div id="divResults">
                
                <table>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            API name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            API description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1.PostalCodeLookup
                        </td>
    
                        <td>        
                            Timezone:
                        </td>
    
                        <td>
                            <select id="selCountry2">
                                <option value="47.01">47.01</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
    
                        <td>
                            <button id="btnRun_2">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            2.Weather
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Continent: 
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtContinent">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Capital: 
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtCapital">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Languages: 
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtLanguages">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Population: 
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtPopulation">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Area (km<sup>2</sup>): 
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtArea">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
    
    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            Latitude:
                        </td>
                        <td id="txtLatitude">
                            
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
                </table>
    
                
    
            </div>
    
            <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/script.js"></script>
    
        </body>
    
    </html>


script.js:
    $('#btnRun').click(function() {
    
            $.ajax({
                url: "libs/php/getCountryInfo.php", 
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    country: $('#selCountry').val(),
                    lang: $('#selLanguage').val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
    
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    
                    if (result.status.name == "ok") {
    
                        $('#txtContinent').html(result['data'][0]['continent']);
                        $('#txtCapital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                        $('#txtLanguages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
                        $('#txtPopulation').html(result['data'][0]['population']);
                        $('#txtArea').html(result['data'][0]['areaInSqKm']);
    
                    }
                
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // your error code
                }
            }); 
    
        
        });
    
        $('#btnRun_2').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "libs/php/getTimeZone.php",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    country: $('#selCountry2').val(),
                    lang: $('#selLanguage2').val()
                },
                success: function(result) {
    
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    
                    if (result.status.name == "ok") {
    
                        $('#txtLatitude').html(result['data'][0]['lat']);
                        $('#txtLongitude').html(result['data'][0]['lng']);
                        $('#Timezone').html(result['data'][0]['timezone']);
    
                }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // your error code
                }
            });
    
    
        });

getTimezone.php

    <?php
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);
    
    $url='http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lang'] . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=adeyinka_25';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
    
        curl_close($ch);
    
        $decode = json_decode($result,true);    
    
        $output['status']['code'] = "200";
        $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
        $output['status']['description'] = "success";
        $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
        $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
        echo json_encode($output);
    
    ?>



The response from http://api.geonames.org/ in your getTimezone.php is an error.
I made a request using the following URL (populated the params you have):
https://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat=40.730610&country=US&username=adeyinka_25
{
  "status": {
    "message": "error parsing parameter",
    "value": 14
  }
}

Looking at the GeoNames Documentation, you are missing the lng attribute from the request. Here is a working request URL:
http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=40.730610&lng=-73.935242&username=adeyinka_25
Updating your PHP code above, it should look something like this:
$url='http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['country'] . '&username=adeyinka_25';

Here is the response from that call:
{
  "sunrise":"2024-09-25 06:46",
  "lng":-73.935242,
  "countryCode":"US",
  "gmtOffset":-5,
  "rawOffset":-5,
  "sunset":"2024-09-25 18:46",
  "timezoneId":"America/New_York",
  "dstOffset":-4,
  "countryName":"United States",
  "time":"2024-09-25 13:39",
  "lat":40.73061
}

Additionally, geonames doesn't exist in the response object. This should do the trick for you.
$output['data'] = json_decode($result,true); 

Also, script.js is looking for three values in the response: lat, lng, and timezone. While lat and lng are in the response, timezone is not. It looks like the key you're looking for is timezoneId.
Hopefully, this helps and gets your API working.
